# .htaccess rewriterule does not redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My website is located in a subfolder (gng2) of my public_html folder. I used the second part (##2) of the below .htaccess file to rewrite the url to add the gng2 subfolder to the URI. It works fine, the app loads when I enter my url to the browser.

Now I added the first part (##1)to redirect any requests where the url contains the subfolder as well. I want [www.staging.gonativeguide.com/gng2/en](http://www.staging.gonativeguide.com/gng2/en) to be redirected to [www.staging.gonativeguide.com/en](http://www.staging.gonativeguide.com/en). However this does not work: the first url does not get redirected to the second. Checking the below code on [htaccessTester](https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/), it says it is correct and it should redirect.

My websited is hosted by a shared hosting service and I think the web server is nginx. Any idea why the redirect does not work?

```
RewriteEngine On

## 1. redirect request when it contains the gng2 subfolder.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.gonativeguide.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.staging.gonativeguide.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} gng2/
RewriteRule gng2/(.*) www.staging.gonativeguide.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## 2. rewriting url to add the gng2 subfolder containing the app.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.gonativeguide.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.staging.gonativeguide.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !gng2/
RewriteRule (.*) /gng2/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your current attempt. So I sketched an alternatate version which simplifies the rules and enhances robustness:

```
RewriteEngine On

## 1. redirect request when it contains the gng2 subfolder.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?staging\.gonativeguide\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?gng2/(.*)$ https://www.staging.gonativeguide.com/$1 [R=301]

## 2. redirect request that do not contain the "www" prefix in the host name.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.gonativeguide\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.staging.gonativeguide.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

## 3. rewriting url to add the gng2 subfolder containing the app.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?staging\.gonativeguide\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gng2/
RewriteRule ^ /gng2%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

You need to make absolutely sure that you are not looking at cached results when testing. So always test using a fresh anonymous browser window and use "deep reloads" (CTRL-F5 typically) instead of just reloading.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the really delayed reply (got distracted by some more burning issues). I copy pasted your code, but unfortunately when I enter now staging.gonativeguide.com it does not redirect but returns the below message. Any further hints? "Moved Permanently
The document has moved here.

Additionally, a 301 Moved Permanently error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: I cannot see any issues while taking another look at the directives. You will need to start debugging yourself, I cannot do that for you since only you have access to your system. Start with the http server's error log file. What entries are generated when you make above test request?

Comment: Finally, I could figure this out. I had to move the first section (under ## 1.) to the gng2 subfolder containing the app. This makes sense to me: if the url contains the subfolder as well, the htaccess file in the public directory will not be read, but the one in the subfolder.

Comment: That is not true, the apache http server will always read _all_ distributed configuration files of _all_ folders from the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` up to where the variable `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` points so, so folders further down the hierarchy. That is _one_ of the many reasons that speak _against_ the usage of such distributed configuration files: the performance penalty. Here this means the rule will get considered when implemented in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder. As said: only debugging will allow to find out what exactly is wrong, that is what rewrite debugging is for.

Comment: Nevertheless: great that you found a working setup.